# How can I query for userId's in a nested Array schema with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query for an existing conversation between two users so they don't create more than one conversation in the database if they already have one.

I am not able to get this query to find a conversation that already exists between these two users and tried to use the $all operator.

I was able to query for a conversation by leaving out the "participants" field before so thought it would also work for this query but it isn't.

**I need to find a conversation with BOTH senderId & recID**

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**QUERIES I tried (Not working)**

```
// 1
 const existingConvo = await Conversation.findOne({
      userId: { $all: [newMsg.senderId, newMsg.recId] },
    })
// 2
const existingConvo = await Conversation.findOne({
      userId: [newMsg.senderId, newMsg.recId],
    })
```

**Model**

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    participants: [participantSchema],
  }
)

const participantSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true, // false because we can generate notifications
      ref: `User`,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profileUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might be looking for this syntax:

`{ $and: [ { userId: newMsg.senderId }, { userId: newMsg.recId }] }`

Here's a more detailed info from [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Comment: I actually need to make sure the Conversation has both senderId & recId. Is there a way to ensure the query only returns an object with both properties?

Comment: Then you need to use $and operator instead, I’ve edited my answer